# Multiple CON Expression in ArcGIS Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator

How can I write the following conditional statement with CON?

If ((VALUE = 20 OR IF VALUE=24) then assign value 0, else 1)

```
Con(("Raster1", 0, 1, "VALUE =20")|("Raster1", 0, 1, "VALUE =24"),0,1)
```

I just can´t get this to work

Comment: It seems this works although the operator "OR" doesn´t exist in the RasterCalculator Con("Raster1", 0, 1, "VALUE =20 OR VALUE =24")

Comment: See if in (20,24) will work. It does on tables

Comment: Why use `con` at all?  `!(("Raster1"==20) | ("Raster1"==24))` should do it. You could even use alternatives like `abs("Raster1"-22)!=2`. Although that's a poor choice--it's harder to understand--it leads to a superior solution for floating point rasters, whose values might not exactly equal 20 or 24. You can now easily add a tolerance, such as `abs(abs("Raster1"-22)-2)>0.00001`. That helps you avoid a nasty pitfall. (Note that the details of the syntax depend on what version of ArcGIS you are using.)

Comment: Please help. Trying to create multiple rules using Con tool in ArcMap. Thanks! Con("OM_petit.tif" > 2.5, ("soil_pH_petit.tif" >= 5.5, ("clay_petiit.tif" >24.3) & ("awc_petit.tif" <= 0.09,1,Con(("OM_petit.tif" > 2 and <= 2.5 , ("soil_pH_petit.tif" >= 5.3 and < 5.5, ("clay_petiit.tif" > 18.5 and <= 24.3) & ("awc_petit.tif" > 0.09 and <= 0.16,2,Con(("OM_petit.tif" >= 0.75 and <1.5, ("soil_pH_petit.tif" >= 4.6 and < 5.0, ("clay_petiit.tif" >= 12.5 and <= 15.5) & ("awc_petit.tif" == 0.23,3,Con(("OM_petit.tif" < 0.75, ("soil_pH_petit.tif" < 4.6, ("clay_petiit.tif" < 12.5) & ("awc_petit.tif" > 0.23,4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read about [Raster Calculator operators](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000z7000000).  The bar "|" symbol is the OR operator.

The correct syntax would be:

```
Con(("Raster1" == 20) | ("Raster1" == 24), 0, 1)
```